# Could a medical condition rendering a person incapacitated make someone ineligble for the presidency?

Tags: united-states, president, us-president

Alice wants to run for President of the United States. She qualifies for age, being born in the US and time lived in the US. So far so easy. But Alice *also* is suffering from an illness that results in her being mentally incapable of making decisions or understanding facts fully from time to time. For simplicity, let's assume she has a light case of Alzheimers disease, but it is quickly progressing.

Comment: @MichaelHall 2nd person to find the catch I put into the question: It's if there is a disqualification from presidency for medical reasons, e.d. 25th section 4 that is about a president unable and *temporarily* taking over their duties, or permanent..

Comment: Technically, being in a coma does not render a candidate constitutionally ineligible to run.

Comment: @MichaelHall YEP! That is the point.

Comment: So why then are you even asking?  Because my point is that "eligibility" for any job, (*from POTUS to entry level burger flipper*) presumes a certain level of base human functionality as a minimum requirement.  There's no need to list every possible qualifying or disqualifying medical condition in a job description or posting.  If you have a question about medical privacy for public officials then ask that.  This just isn't a particularly useful question as written.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no constitutional impediment to electing Alice, or to Alice holding office.

Of course, Section 4 of the Twenty-Fifth Amendment allows the vice president and cabinet to declare the President unable to discharge the duties of the office, but this is a separate issue than you're asking about.

Comment: Even before the 25th Amendment, the original Constitution in Article 2, section 1, clause 6, provided that in the case of the President being unable to discharge the powers of the office, the powers will devolve to the Vice President. And the 25th Amendment didn't repeal this. But the Constitution is silent on how an Article 2 disability would be determined, so absent a 25th amendment declaration, it might lead to a constitutional crisis.

Answer (score 0):

There are only 3 requirements to be eligible:

- Be natural born
- Be at least 35 years old
- Have been a resident for 14 years

An illness, even Alzheimer's, is not disqualifying.